# MS SQL column encryption without certificate

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, aes, x509certificate

I am trying to encrypt one of my sensitive columns in a SQL Server table. 
I tried AES256 encryption with this script, and it works perfect. 
But I don't want to create Certificates, or Symmetric Keys on my SQL Server as it may be a security problem later. 
How can I encrypt the data with a single password or key in my query ? 
Another problem with this method is, I can use only a single master password for 
my encryption.

```
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION
    BY PASSWORD = '$Passw0rd'
    GO

    CREATE CERTIFICATE AESEncryptTestCert
    WITH SUBJECT = 'AESEncrypt'
    GO

    CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY AESEncrypt
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256 ENCRYPTION -- TRIPLE_DES ENCRYPTION
    BY CERTIFICATE AESEncryptTestCert;


   OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY AESEncrypt DECRYPTION
   BY CERTIFICATE AESEncryptTestCert 
   SELECT ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('AESEncrypt'),'The text to be encrypted');
```

Comment: And what's the problem you are trying to solve with this column encryption?

Comment: the column contains the most sensitive data, and the table is accessible to many people through linked-table in access files.
I don't want them to see the particular column values, but the people who uses another application.

Comment: I don't know your environment, but can't granting access rights and/or views be the solution?

Comment: my plan is to store encrypted column values to the table, 
and read it using a stored-procedure where I can give the password/key as a parameter. 
I didn't find any solution which uses custom key/password rather than the master password for sql-encryption.

Comment: Why not encrypt it before going to SQL then?

Comment: my boss doesn't want it. he tells me to create a stored procedure where he can give a password as parameter, and get the result set. 
This parameter can be same as the admin password.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [EncryptByPassPhrase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357(v=sql.110).aspx) and [DecryptByPassPhrase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188910(v=sql.110).aspx), for example:

```
DECLARE @CypherText varbinary(8000)
DECLARE @ClearText varchar(128) = 'Text to encrypt'

SET @CypherText = EncryptByPassPhrase ('MyP@ssword123', @ClearText)

DECLARE @DecryptedText varchar(128)
SET @DecryptedText = DecryptByPassPhrase('MyP@ssword123', @CypherText)

SELECT @CypherText AS CypherText, @DecryptedText As DecryptedText
```

**EDIT:**
The above code produces the following output

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|                                 CypherText                                  |  DecryptedText  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| 0x01000000F1D813F399246484FDA8D7C7D22BFBCF748D3F6033D4E9980FCDC58A387A1A93 | Text to encrypt |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```